# search/replace content of xml

Tags: python, elementtree

I've been successful using xml.etree.ElementTree to parse an xml, search for content, then write this to a different xml. However, I just worked with text, inside of a singe tag.

```
import os, sys, glob, xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
path = r"G:\\63D RRC GIS Data\\metadata\\general\\2010_contract"
for fn in os.listdir(path):
    filepaths = glob.glob(path + os.sep + fn + os.sep + "*overall.xml")
    for filepath in filepaths:
        (pa, filename) = os.path.split(filepath)
        ####use this section to grab element text from old, archived metadata files; this text then gets put into current, working .xml###
        root = ET.parse(pa + os.sep + "archive" + os.sep + "base_metadata_overall.xml").getroot()

        iterator = root.getiterator()
        for item in iterator:
            if item.tag == "abstract":
                correct_abstract = item.text

        root2 = ET.parse(pa + os.sep + "base_metadata_overall.xml").getroot()

        iterator2 = root2.getiterator("descript")
        for item in iterator2:
            if item.tag == "abstract":
                old_abstract = item.find("abstract")
                old_abstract_text = old_abstract.text
                item.remove(old_abstract)
                new_symbol_abstract = ET.SubElement(item, "title")
                new_symbol_abstract.text = correct_abstract                
        tree = ET.ElementTree(root2)
        tree.write(pa + os.sep + "base_metadata_overall.xml")
        print "created --- " + filename + " metadata"
```

But now, I need to:

1) search an xml and grab everything between "attr" tags, below is example:

```
<attr><attrlabl Sync="TRUE">OBJECTID</attrlabl><attalias Sync="TRUE">ObjectIdentifier</attalias><attrtype Sync="TRUE">OID</attrtype><attwidth Sync="TRUE">4</attwidth><atprecis Sync="TRUE">0</atprecis><attscale Sync="TRUE">0</attscale><attrdef Sync="TRUE">Internal feature number.</attrdef></attr>
```

2) Now, I need to open a different xml and search for all content between the same "attr" tag and replace with the above.

Basically, what I was doing before, but ignoring subelements, attributes, ect... between "attr" tags and treat it like text.

thanks!!

Please bear with me, this forum is a little different (posting) then Im used to!

Here's what I have so far:

```
import os, sys, glob, re, xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from lxml import etree

path = r"C:\\temp\\python\\xml"
for fn in os.listdir(path):
    filepaths = glob.glob(path + os.sep + fn + os.sep +  "*overall.xml")
    for filepath in filepaths:
            (pa, filename) = os.path.split(filepath)

            xml = open(pa + os.sep + "attributes.xml")
            xmltext = xml.read()
            correct_attrs = re.findall("<attr> (.*?)</attr>",xmltext,re.DOTALL)
            for item in correct_attrs:
                correct_attribute = "<attr>" + item + "</attr>"

                xml2 = open(pa + os.sep + "base_metadata_overall.xml")
                xmltext2 = xml2.read()
                old_attrs = re.findall("<attr>(.*?)</attr>",xmltext,re.DOTALL)
                for item2 in old_attrs:
                    old_attribute = "<attr>" + item + "</attr>"               



                    old = etree.fromstring(old_attribute)
                    replacement = new.xpath('//attr')
                    for attr in old.xpath('//attr'):
                        attr.getparent().replace(attr, copy.deepcopy(replacement))
                        print lxml.etree.tostring(old)
```

got this working, see below, even figured out how to export to new .xml
However, If the # of attr's is dif. from source to dest, I get the following error, any suggestions?

node = replacements.pop()

IndexError: pop from empty list

```
import os, sys, glob, re, copy, lxml, xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from lxml import etree
path = r"C:\\temp\\python\\xml"
for fn in os.listdir(path):
filepaths = glob.glob(path + os.sep + fn + os.sep + "*overall.xml")
for filepath in filepaths:
        xmlatributes = open(pa + os.sep + "attributes.xml")
        xmlatributes_txt = xmlatributes.read()
        xmltarget = open(pa + os.sep + "base_metadata_overall.xml")
        xmltarget_txt = xmltarget.read()
        source = lxml.etree.fromstring(xmlatributes_txt)
        dest = lxml.etree.fromstring(xmltarget_txt)            




        replacements = source.xpath('//attr')
        replacements.reverse()


        for attr in dest.xpath('//attr'):
            node = replacements.pop()
            attr.getparent().replace(attr, copy.deepcopy(node))
        #print lxml.etree.tostring(dest)
        tree = ET.ElementTree(dest)
        tree.write (pa + os.sep + "edited_metadata.xml")
        print fn + "--- sucessfully edited"
```

**update 5/16/2011**
restructured a few things to fix the "IndexError: pop from empty list" error mentioned above. Realized that the replacement of the "attr" tags will not always be a 1-to-1 replacement. For ex. sometimes the source .xml has 20 attr's and the destination .xml has 25 attr's. In this case, the 1-to-1 replacement would choke.

Anyway, the below will remove all attr's, then replace with the source attr's. It also checks for another tag, "subtype" if it exists, it adds them after the attr's, but inside the "detailed" tags.

thanks again to everyone who helped.

```
import os, sys, glob, re, copy, lxml, xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from lxml import etree
path = r"G:\\63D RRC GIS Data\\metadata\\general\\2010_contract"
#path = r"C:\\temp\python\\xml"
for fn in os.listdir(path):
    correct_title = fn.replace ('_', ' ') + " various facilities"
    correct_fc_name = fn.replace ('_', ' ')
    filepaths = glob.glob(path + os.sep + fn + os.sep + "*overall.xml")
    for filepath in filepaths:
        print "-----" + fn + "-----"
        (pa, filename) = os.path.split(filepath)
        xmlatributes = open(pa + os.sep + "attributes.xml")
        xmlatributes_txt = xmlatributes.read()
        xmltarget = open(pa + os.sep + "base_metadata_overall.xml")
        xmltarget_txt = xmltarget.read()
        source = lxml.etree.fromstring(xmlatributes_txt)
        dest = lxml.etree.fromstring(xmltarget_txt)
        replacements = source.xpath('//attr')
        replacesubtypes = source.xpath('//subtype')
        subtype_true_f = len(replacesubtypes)

        attrtag = dest.xpath('//attr')
        #print len(attrtag)
        num_realatrs = len(replacements)
        for n in attrtag:
            n.getparent().remove(n)
        print n.tag + " removed"

        detailedtag = dest.xpath('//detailed')
        for n2 in detailedtag:
            pos = 0
            for realatrs in replacements:
                n2.insert(pos + 1, realatrs)
            print "attr's replaced"
            if subtype_true_f >= 1:
                #print subtype_true_f
                for realsubtypes in replacesubtypes:
                   n2.insert(num_realatrs + 1, realsubtypes)
                print "subtype's replaced"

        tree = ET.ElementTree(dest)
        tree.write (pa + os.sep + "base_metadata_overall_v2.xml")
        print fn + "--- sucessfully edited"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of using `lxml` to do this. I'm not *exactly* sure how you want the `<attr/>` nodes replaced, but this example should provide a pattern you can reuse.

**Update** - I changed it to replace each `<attr>` in tree2 with the corresponding node from tree1, in document order:

```
import copy
import lxml.etree

xml1 = '''<root><attr><chaos foo="0"/></attr><attr><arena foo="1"/></attr></root>'''
xml2 = '''<tree><attr><one/></attr><attr><two/></attr></tree>'''
tree1 = lxml.etree.fromstring(xml1)
tree2 = lxml.etree.fromstring(xml2)

# select <attr/> nodes from tree1, will be used to replace corresponding
# nodes in tree2
replacements = tree1.xpath('//attr')
replacements.reverse()

for attr in tree2.xpath('//attr'):
    # replace the attr node in tree2 with 'replacement' from tree1
    node = replacements.pop()
    attr.getparent().replace(attr, copy.deepcopy(node))

print lxml.etree.tostring(tree2)
```

Result:

```
<tree>
  <attr><chaos foo="0"/></attr>
  <attr><arena foo="1"/></attr>
</tree>
```

Comment: thanks. should have been clearer in my orig. post. There are several "attr" attributes in the source AND the destination xml, and they are all contain different content. I'd like to delete all "attr" in the destination, and replace with all "attr" from source.

Comment: I can grab the orig. "attr" contents and the source "attr" contents but I'm not sure how to do the replacement??

Comment: How do you determine which dest attr gets replaced by which source attr?  Do you replace them in document order?

Comment: it doesn't matter what dest. attr gets replaced with which source attr. In reality, I need to treat all attr's as one group. Remove all; replace all. See the code i've been working on in orig. post. I can atleast extract all source and dest. attr's now! thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like something that XSL-T transformations were made for.  Have you tried that?

I'd also recommend a library like Beautiful Soup for parsing and manipulating XML.

Comment: On a program , I measured execution's times and BeautifulSoup appeared to be 1000 times slower than a regex solution. I don't pretend it's general, it's a case, but such a difference is significant though